# span textContent split returns undefined in javascript funtion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to help a friend out with the following javascript. We both are new to javascript.

We are trying to convert the date string to a different format. Based on internet search we understand that the date function expects the input string to be Date(year, month, day) format. To achieve that we need to parse the input string and send it in the expected format. We have not got a clue why string split on span tag's textcontent (that contains the date string) is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ready(callback){

    if (document.readyState!='loading') callback();
    else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
    else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
        if (document.readyState=='complete') callback();
    });
}
    window.onload = ready(function() {
        var dateString = document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent.trim();
        var sMonth = dateString.split("/")[0];
        var sDay = dateString.split("/")[1];
        var sYear = dateString.split("/")[2];
        document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent=sMonth;
    });
</script>
```

The html has the following span tag.

```
<span id="dateFormatter">26/06/1993</span>
```

sMonth returns 26/06/1993, whereas sDay and sYear returns undefined.

Comment: I don't think split can ever return undefined? It might return an empty array though.

Comment: I stuck your code in a snippet and it works fine...

Comment: Why do you use split 3 times instead of doing it once and reference the variable? `var parts = dateString.split("/"); var sMonth = parts[0];`

Comment: It makes no sense to have onload and ready...... Where did you get that from? If onload fires, ready already fired.

Comment: The date in the spantag is a variable at project level,  {{$F.DATE}}. I was just playing with onload and ready based on examples to see if I can ensure the js runs only after the date substitution happens. Unfortunately I just found out that the split failed since it had run on the variable reference instead of the value. Is there any way to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string from your div is invalid format if you want to convert to a datestring. A valid string would be: yyyy-mm-dd. If you have already a dateobject you can use the function to format the date.

Like that:

#### Update

```js
callback();
window.addEventListener('load', function () {           
      var dateString = document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent.trim();
      console.log(dateString)
      let dateArr = dateString.split("/");
      var sDay = dateArr[0];
      var sMonth = dateArr[1];
      var sYear = dateArr[2];
      let newDateString = (sYear + '-' +  sMonth + '-' + sDay);
      let d = new Date(newDateString);
      console.log(d);
      document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent=d.toLocaleString();
});
```

```html
<span id="dateFormatter">26/06/1993</span>
```

##### old snippet

```js
function ready(callback) {

    if (document.readyState!='loading') callback();
    else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
    else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
        if (document.readyState=='complete') callback();
    });
}

    window.onload = ready(function() {
      var dateString = document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent.trim();
      console.log(dateString)
      let dateArr = dateString.split("/");
      var sDay = dateArr[0];
      var sMonth = dateArr[1];
      var sYear = dateArr[2];
      let newDateString = (sYear + '-' +  sMonth + '-' + sDay);
      let d = new Date(newDateString);
      console.log(d);
      document.getElementById("dateFormatter").textContent=d;
    });
```

```html
<span id="dateFormatter">26/06/1993</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs! The date in the span tag is a variable. {{$F.DATE}} This value is dynamically loaded when this HTML is generated. In the console log the variable reference is seen instead of the date value. Hence the split failed. Is there a way I can ensure this only runs after the variable substitution has happened ?

Comment: @VijayendarGururaja unfortunately, i do not understand the following thing:  `In the console log the variable reference is seen instead of the date value.` Can you explain what are you exectly mean, please?

Comment: For debugging, to check if the date input string is valid, I added console.log(dateString). It outputs {{$F.DATE}} instead of the date value. {{$F.DATE}} is a project variable that gets substituted with the actual date value when the html is generated.

Comment: @VijayendarGururaja then you make sure that your script above is running after the generating the dom. What is the name of the html generator whcih include these "project variable"?

Comment: I don't have access to other project files. Only this html to work with. sorry  I am not sure how to get the name of html generator. And to ensure Dom is loaded first I added the ready() function. I think the way in which it's called is incorrect. I.e with onload. I may have to rework that part I guess.

Comment: @VijayendarGururaja i updated my answear and include an eventlistener to make sure that the page already loaded. after that "the datestring parser" starts.

Comment: I tried the updated snippet. I am not getting the console log and the date format also has not changed. In the Old snippet, I was getting the console log, which I no longer get in the new snippet.

Comment: @VijayendarGururaja I don't have enough information to know what the problem is. What does the callback() function do? I can only guess. Maybe set callback(); before the `window.addEventListener('load', function () {... }` I have adjusted it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you I came pretty close to using this solution, but could not dig further. for debugging, I was able to use "click" event listener and get it working, but for some reason 'load' did not work and the js kept racing ahead before the html got generated. However it was great learning from your inputs and I am sure this answers the question in topic.

Comment: @VijayendarGururaja You welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the textContent of the span to only show the value of `sMonth` and when that happens, the span will only have "26" as its body (whitch btw is wrong if you write dates like so) - and actually should not be "26/06/1993" if the code is right.

Also, if you want to run the script multiple times, try setting the span's textContent to `sDay+"/"+sMonth+"/"+sYear` so it's the same formatting you expect the script to work with. The code you provided sets the span's value to "26" then if you run it again, it tries to split "26" along "/"-s, which of course ends up being incorrect.